# Terminology in book "FP in Scala" : "we can treat the objects of our APIs as black boxes"

Tags: scala, functional-programming, terminology

What is the meaning of the phrase "we can treat the objects of our APIs as black boxes" in the book [FP in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/)
(highlighted with red in the picture and marked with red question mark)  ?

What are objects of the API?  (EDIT: I cannot seem to find the definition for this term "object of API" in the book, at least not in the first 113 pages, also I believe the writers do not refer to objects in the object-oriented sense.)

What is the definition of object in this context ?

In what sense can these objects be black boxes ?

Black boxes with respect to what ?

Hiding what, how, why ?

Encapsulating what, how, why ?

[image]

Comment: the accepted general meaning of "black box" AFAIUI, is with respect to what's *inside* them. It's only defined by how it interacts with the outer world, and we don't know/don't care what's inside, and how it does what it does - only *what* it does (i.e. how in interacts). That's a *general* answer, don't know about this book specifically.

Comment: so in other words it could be said, "we can rely on them to behave the same way (re: API) in all circumstances". Here's an example: a simple generator of consecutive integers, from a starting number that we specify when we start it. If it hides the counter inside, so no code outside has access to it ("encapsulation"), we can rely on it to produce a sequence of integers in order. But if it uses a global variable to hold its current value, then it can't be relied upon anymore - some other code *could* change the value of that counter, and thus the produced numbers won't be in order.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, it makes sense, I see the connection.

Comment: If you downvote explain what is wrong with the question, otherwise you are a coward who is afraid to show his face to defend his opinion. Down with covard downvoters!

Answer (score 4):

> What are objects of the API?

Anything your API exposes publicly

> What is the definition of object in this context ?

See above. It's an informal way of referring to anything your API exposes.

> In what sense can these objects be black boxes?

In the sense that you don't care about their internals. The implementation is clearly separated from the interface, so all you need to know when you use pieces of the API is their contract, i.e. what's their expected output given a set of inputs.

> Black boxes with respect to what?

Black boxes with respect to anything outside them, for instance your code which uses them

> Hiding what, how, why?

They hide their internals (i.e. their implementation) by conforming to a known contract. Why? Because this allows for modularization, which carries along great benefits, such as code reuse, maintainability and simplicity.

> Encapsulating what, how, why?

This is kind of the same question as before. Encapsulating means separating different components and decoupling their interfaces from their internals. For what, how and why, see above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, may I kindly ask if you have read this book already (or if not the whole book then at least chapter 7) ? I am asking this because I was hoping for an answer that relates more to the spirit of the book, perhaps giving specific examples. Currently your answer seems a little bit vague. Especially "Anything your API exposes publicly" is very vague. Could please be more specific? What is specifically in this case an object (for this particular API described in the 7th chapter of the book) ?

Comment: @jhegedus I'm reading the book, but I haven't finished chapter 7 yet. Anyway it's not much different than what I already said: the objects of the APIs are the set of types the algebra defines (`Par[A]`, ...) and the functions (`map2`, `unit`,...).

In the chapter you see how it's important to have laws that ensure the soundness of the API, i.e. - in the specific context - that the result of each function doesn't depend on where and when it's executed, but only on its inputs. In this sense is a blackbox, that can be moved around and replaced with its result (i.e. it's referentially transparent)

Comment: So black box is a synonym for "referentially transparent" ?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a synonym as it looks informal in that context, but yes, it's clearly referring to the same concept.

Comment: A related question: could you give an example how the property of the objects of the API being a "blackbox" could be violated? I.e. maybe it's easier to understand what is "being a blackbox" by giving a counterexample, i.e. how can the objects of an API *not* be a "blackbox" ? If they (the functions) can throw exceptions for example? How can the types be or not be a blackbox?

Comment: simple answer is: by having side effects

Comment: So fork in this case is not referentially transparent i.e. not a blackbox because it can deadlock depending on the ExecutorService ? I think this buggy implementation of fork is actually referentially transparent. Given the same input, we ALWAYS get the same output. In the case of deadlock the output is bottom.

Comment: Section 7.4.3 should address precisely this issue

Comment: Exactly, it does, and according to that section, fork is referentially transparent, but according to you "blackbox" means referentially transparent, but fork is referentially transparent so it should be a "blackbox" too, according to your answer, but according to the authors (as far as I can interpet this book page), fork is not a "blackbox". So in this case we are back to square one, and we don't seem to have a single clue about what the authors might have meant by "blackbox".

Comment: I just don't see how fork is not referentially transparent. If it deadlocks then its value is bottom, that has nothing to do with referential transparency.

Comment: I hope the rest of the book will give some clarification on the vague term "blackbox".